# Puppet Enterprise agent for AMZN Linux ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet-enterprise

Anyone able to install puppet enterprise agent on AWS Linux ami image (amzn-2017.03-x86_64.bash)

OS on agent node is:

## uname -a:

Linux ip-172-32-3-123 4.9.27-14.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 10 01:58:40 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Issue:

## curl -k https://puppet:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash

This method of agent installation is not supported for amzn-2017.03-x86_64 in 
Puppet Enterprise v2017.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Puppet Enterprise does not support agent on AWS amzn linux node at this stage. I have confirmed this with the Puppet support team.